# Large difference between number of image sensor pixels and pixels in the image from my iPhone

Tags: sensor, resolution, iphone, pixels, photosites

According to the [specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp685?locale=en_US) given by Apple, the iPhone 5s camera has 8 megapixels. I assume that this is supposed to mean that the image sensor has 8 million photosites, and I would appreciate it if someone could confirm this.

Now when I import a photo from the iPhone to my laptop, the photo has a resolution of 1632 x 1224 pixels (as determined by looking at the photo properties). This is a total of about 2MP.

From the answer given by jrista in [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9738/why-are-effective-pixels-greater-than-the-actual-resolution), I can understand why there are more photosites on the sensor than pixels in the image, but that explanation doesn't account for a difference of several million. Where is this discrepancy coming from?

Comment: Are you 100% sure your camera application is taking full resolution images?

Comment: What app did you use?

Comment: yup, the problem was that I wasn't using the default camera app. I get the full resolution when I use the camera app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My iPhone 5S takes 8 megapixel images, specifically, 3264x2448 pixels. This is native size.  This is speaking of still images, not the movie images which of course are 1920x1080 or 2 megapixels.

However Apple likes to offer lots of opportunity to export them resampled much smaller, especially for sending with email or text messages, when a large image can be a problem in ill favor.   Viewing them on another phone screen can only use about 0.2 megapixels.

But if you download them by connecting the power cord to a  computer USB port, you can get the full 8 megapixel images.